" did" or "do"?
"What did you want to do that for?”
“You can count on me right down the line,” he said.
“You want to knock your brains out?”
“You can count on me. Don’t you believe me?"
"I get along all right."
It is a dialogue between a man and a woman. He wanted to hit his head on the bar because the woman didn't accept his apology , so he did what he had said. The woman held him and prevented him from hurting himself. My question is when the woman says, " You want to knock ...." Does she ask in the past or present tense ? I mean, before her question, should it be "did" or " do"? I think the correct one is " do," but I have this book translated in another language and there used " did" and asked in the past tense.

This part of your question is unclear:
In before her question, should it be "did" or " do"?  are you asking whether it should be What did you want to ... or What do you want to ...?

Is she talking about what the man tried to do, or about what he might still be trying to do? Is she still restraining him?

@SeowjoohengSingapore I mean, "do you want to knock your brains out?” or "did You want to knock your brains out?”

@Peter yes I want to know which one is correct?  "Is she talking about what the man tried to do, or about what he might still be trying to do?"

Your extract does not make this clear. One might guess that she thought the man might still want to hit his head, in which case using either did or do would be correct.

@Peter I think the correct one is " do you want ...", because she is so naive. So when he says " you can count ..." she thinks he wants to hit his head on the bar again"

The mood and tone of the man were not described when he said
"You can count on me. Don’t you believe me?" Hence we can't assume whether he had calmed down, and need to state our reasons when we choose the tense.


Do you want to knock your brains out?


Did you want to knock your brains out?

If the man had calmed down, we use did.  The woman's questioning would then just serve to find out something that was past.
If he was still attempting to harm himself, we use do.
Edit
Did is also possible even if the man still had intention to harm himself; the woman could be enquiring about a past intention which led to the present act.

I mean this sentence : "You can count on me right down the line,” he said. He said it figuratively but she takes it literally. And she thinks he realy wants to knock his brains out, and they are somehow drunk.

Whichever way the woman interpreted or misinterpreted
the conversation, if she believed the man was still attempting to hit his head, we use do.

Certainly in the UK we might use the simple past ('did') when the person is still carrying out the activity, because we are enquiring about a past intention which led to the present act.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I have incorporated that.
